# How can I read lines from a .txt file into two separate buffers?

Tags: c, file-io, system-calls

I have two buffers `char *buffer1` and `char *buffer2` which are allocated on the heap, using `malloc`. From a text file, I want to read one line into `buffer1` and the second line into `buffer2`, how can I accomplish this under the same while-loop?

So far, I have figured out how to read the first line of text into `buffer1`:

```
int i = 0;
while (read(input_fd, &buffer1[i], 1) == 1) {
    // check if the line is longer than MAX_LINE_LENGTH
    // otherwise, read the first line into buffer1
    if (buffer1 > MAX_LINE_LENGTH) {
        perror("Error: The line read in is longer than the allocated buffer.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        // checking for end of line, then appending the null
        // character to the right of the last read char in buffer1
        // to indicate the line is over
        if (buffer1[i] == '\n' || buffer1[i] == 0x0) {
            buffer1[i] = '\0';

            // write the first line in buffer1 to the terminal
            write(output_fd, buffer1, strlen(buffer1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a pointer to the buffer, instead of using the buffer directly. Do you want to read only two lines, or do read an arbitrary number of lines and alternate?

Comment: @Devolus I want to read multiple lines until EOF whilst alternating b/w buffer1 and buffer2. For example, "This is sentence one." would be read into buffer1 and the next adjacent sentence, say, "This is the next sentence." would be read into buffer2 and so forth until EOF.

Comment: *"buffer1 > MAX_LINE_LENGTH"* - Where did you get that idea? I suppose the compiler warned you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
if (buffer1 > MAX_LINE_LENGTH) {
```

is wrong, because it compares the pointer itself, instead of the length of the string. This condition will most likely always be true. Since you never increase `i` you always read 1 byte in the same position, so at least there will be no harm because of that, even though it is probably not what you intended.

```
int i = 0;
char *p = buffer1;
while (read(input_fd, &p[i], 1) == 1)
{
    if (p[i] == '\n')
    {
        p[i] = '\0';
        write(output_fd, p, i);
        i = 0;
        if (p == buffer1)
           p = buffer2;
        else
           p = buffer1;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
        if (i > MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
        {
            perror("Error: The line read in is longer than the allocated buffer.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what `if (p == buffer1)` is doing?

Comment: If you are currently running on buffer1 it switches to buffer2 otherwise the other way. This compares which buffer pointer is currently in use.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                
static void *                                                                      
xmalloc(size_t s)                                                                  
{                                                                                  
        void *p = malloc(s);                                                       
        if( p == NULL ){                                                           
                perror("malloc");                                                  
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                
        }                                                                          
        return p;                                                                  
}                                                                                  
int                                                                                
main(void)                                                                         
{                                                                                  
        char *buffer1 = xmalloc(256);                                              
        char *buffer2 = xmalloc(256);                                              
        buffer1[0] = buffer2[0] = '\0';                                            
        buffer1[255] = buffer2[255] = 'x';                                         
        char *ip = buffer1;                                                        
        while( fgets(ip, 256, stdin) != NULL ){                                    
                if( ip[255] != 'x' ){                                              
                        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input: line too long\n");         
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                        
                }                                                                                                     
                ip = ip == buffer1 ? buffer2 : buffer1;                            
        }                                                                          
        return 0;                                                                  
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I'm new to C so I don't understand much of what your source code is doing. Could you please explain? Also, I'm only allowed to use system calls as this is for an assignment.

Comment: If you're using `read` instead of `fgets`, it really won't be possible to read each line directly into the appropriate buffer.  Perhaps you are expected to implement `fgets` functionality.  You'll need to read into a generic buffer and copy data into buffer1 or buffer2 after you find a line break.  Or perhaps you should just read one character at a time to the appropriate location.  ie, when you see a `'\n'`, switch the buffer that `ip` points to.